# MVC pattern in JAVA

Tags: java, model-view-controller, design-patterns

What are the advantages and disadvantages in MVC patterns when it's using in Java?

Answer (score 4):

Advantages and Disadvantages of *any* design pattern do not depend on any language!

Comment: I slightly disagree. Some design pattern are harder/clunkier to implement in some languages and simply unnecessary in others (Examples: 1. Strategy pattern can become unwieldly in Java, due to the verbose nature of anonymous classes. 2. Visitor pattern is not necessary in languages that support multiple dispatch (LISP)).

Comment: I agree with you, for *some* pattern language does matter, but I think they are just a minority

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer is independent of the language and even the first line of Wikipedia answers  it quite well: "The pattern isolates business logic from input and presentation, permitting independent development, testing and maintenance of each." Wikipedia: [Model-view-controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

Answer (score 1):

Advantages

1. Clear separation between presentation logic & business Logic
2. All classes & objects are independent of each other, so as to change one class doesn't   need alteration in other classes
3. Parallel development is possible
4. Easy maintenance of code for future enhancement

Disadvantages

1. Increase Complexity
2. Time consuming
3. Knowledge of multiple technologies are required
4. If you change controller code then

   i. We need to recompile the class & redeploy the Application

   ii. We need to write separate code for that file

Answer (score 0):

MVC Pattern is widely used in Java. Most of the java web frameworks are built on MVC architecture. As stated in a previous reply "Advantages and Disadvantages of any design pattern do not depend on any language". This is 90% percent true.

JSP is well fitted for MVC Pattern. The JSP architecture has a lot of features and concepts that makes MVC easily implementable in Java, and a few classes suitable for MVC: ServletController to be used in the controller layer, JSP files to be used in presentation layer; controller can delegate the calls to other controllers, of to jsp pages.

However, JSP is just an java "extension", does not represent java core. Writing a new MVC framework from scratch is possible, and there are many java JSP alternatives out there, many based on MVC(Struts2/WebWorks for example).

Writing a new MVC framework from scratch in java is (almost) as easy/hard as writing it in another language.